# I need date for the file I created in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", but I don't understand what datetime.datetime.timstamp() returns

Tags: python, python-datetime

The code I've written so far is included below. I am under the
impression that assigning a variable to
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp() will result in a list, so I created
my Python code like below. I want my function to return the time
that I first created my file as a substring of a string in the format
"yyyy-mm-dd". I would greatly appreciate any help in making this code work correctly.

```
import os
import datetime

def file_date(filename):
  # Create the file in the current directory
  with open(filename, "x") as file1:
    pass
  timestamp = os.path.getmtime(file1)
  # Convert the timestamp into a readable format, then into a string
  list1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
  str1 = "-".join(list1)
  # Return just the date portion 
  # Hint: how many characters are in “yyyy-mm-dd”? 
  return ("{str1[0:9]}".format(str1)

print(file_date("newfile.txt")) 
# Should be today's date in the format of yyyy-mm-dd
```

Comment: what's the output of `print(list1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list1 is an object of type datetime.datetime to format it as a string use

```
time_in_string = list1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

No. `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` is a named constructor (a constructor "constructs" instances of a class) for `datetime` instances (object of the datetime class). This means that calling `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)` will give you a datetime object corresponding to that timestamp and not a list. When you print the datetime instance you get `datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 13, 13, 15, 1, 270342)`.

To parse the `datetime` instance as a formatted time string "yyyy-mm-dd", you can use

`list1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

where %Y is the year %m is the zero padded month and %d is the zero padded day

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a try this function -

```
>>> import os
>>> import platform
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> 
>>> def file_creation(path_to_file):
...     if platform.system() == 'Windows':
...             dt = os.path.getctime(path_to_file)
...     else:
...             stat = os.stat(path_to_file)
...             try:
...                     dt = stat.st_birthtime
...             except AttributeError:
...                     dt = stat.st_mtime
...     return datetime.fromtimestamp(dt).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
... 
>>> 
>>> file_creation('test.sh')
'2018-06-18'
```

Answer (score 0):

**getmtime** and **getctime** takes path instead of the file object

 type of (datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)) is **'datetime.datetime'**, not a list

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime


def file_date(filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as file1:
        pass

    path = os.path.abspath(filename)

    timestamp = os.path.getctime(path)

    date_created = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

    str_DT = date_created.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    return str_DT


print(file_date("file2.txt"))
```